# Mock class prototype in javascript with jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I am currently on a project and i need to `mock` a certain `constructor` `class` `prototype` to run test so it doesn't deal directly with my `database`. I already tried researching and discovered i need to `import` the `module` into my `mock` file and then `export` it to my `test` file and use `jest.setMock()` to replace the module in my `test.js` file.  Below is the code to what i have tried.

I have an `Admin` `constructor` `class` with a delete function in its `prototype` responsible for deleting from `db`

**admin.js**

```
function Admin(username, email, password, access) {
    Users.call(this, username, email, password, access);
}

Admin.constructor = Admin;

Admin.prototype.deleteSingleUser = function(id, accountType) {
   this.id = id;
   this.accountType = accountType;

    let response = "";

    if(this.accountType === "admin") {
        for(let i in dbData.admin) {
            if(dbData.admin[i].id === this.id) {
                dbData.admin.splice(i, 1);
                fs.writeFileSync('db.json', JSON.stringify(dbData, null, 2));
                console.log(dbData.admin);
                response = "Account successfully deleted";
            }
            else {
                response = "There is no user registered with this ID";
            }
        }
    }
    else if(this.accountType === "user") {
        for(let i in dbData.users) {
            if(dbData.users[i].id === this.id) {
                dbData.users.splice(i, 1);
                fs.writeFileSync('db.json', JSON.stringify(dbData, null, 2));
                console.log(dbData.users);
                response = "Account successfully deleted";
            }
            else {
                response = "There is no user registered with this ID";
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        response = "Kindly use a valid account type";
    }
    console.log(response);
    return response;
};
```

Then in my `__mocks__` directory i have an `admin.js` file containing a `mock` database and my `mock` delete code

**__mocks__/admin.js**

```
//Imported the admin.js

let Admin = require("../admin");

//Created a mock database
let mockDb = {
    "users": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "username": "aaa",
            "email": "aaa@gmail.com",
            "password": "aaa",
            "access": "user"
        }
    ],
    "admin": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "username": "bbb",
            "email": "bbb@gmail.com",
            "password": "bbb",
            "access": "admin"
        }
    ]
} 

//My mock delete function

Admin.prototype.deleteSingleUser = function(id, accountType) {
    this.id = id;
    this.accountType = accountType;

    let response = "";

    if (this.accountType === "admin") {
        if(mockDb.admin[0].id === this.id) {
            response = "Account successfully deleted";
        }
        else {
            response = "There is no user registered with this ID";
        }
    }
    else if (this.accountType === "user") {
        if(mockDb.users[0].id === this.id) {
            response = "Account successfully deleted";
        }
        else {
            response = "There is no user registered with this ID";
        }
    }
    console.log("Its using the mock");
    return response;
};
module.exports = Admin;
```

Then in my `__test__` folder i have a `test.js` file with my test cases

**__test__/test.js**

```
const Admin = require("../admin");
jest.setMock("Admin", require("../__mocks__/admin"));

test("Should check if admin can delete with a wrong id", () => {
    let response = Admin.prototype.deleteSingleUser(0, "user");
    expect(response).toBe("There is no user registered with this ID");
});
test("Should check if admin can delete a user", () => {
    let response = Admin.prototype.deleteSingleUser(1, "user");
    expect(response).toBe("Account successfully deleted");
});
```

Neither of the test cases pass but both `throw` an `error` saying

> Test suite failed to run
>
> Cannot find module 'Admin' from 'test.js'
>
> 2 | const Users = require("../main");
>
> 3 | const Admin = require("../admin");
>
> 4 | jest.setMock("Admin", require("../**mocks**/admin"));
>
> |      ^
>
> 5 | const order = require("../order");
>
> 6 | let mocks = require("../**mocks**/admin");
>
> 7 | let dbData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('db.json'));
>
> at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:229:17)
>
> at Object.setMock (**test**/test.js:4:6)

I feel i am not doing something right but i can't seem to point it out. Please what is the issue and how do i fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems alright. You just need to set your `jest.setMock()` to point to the right file.

`jest.setMock()` takes two parameters `jest.setMock(moduleName, moduleExports)`. The `moduleName` should point to the file containing the `module` your are mocking and `moduleExports` to the file containing your mock module. In other words, change in your

**__test__/test.js**

```
jest.setMock("Admin", require("../__mocks__/admin"));
```

to

```
jest.setMock("../admin", require("../__mocks__/admin"));
```

And you should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use `jest.setMock` at all.

You just need to activate the [manual mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-user-modules) you created for your user module by doing this:

```
jest.mock('../admin');  // <= activate the manual mock
```

---

**Details**

The docs for [`jest.setMock`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestsetmockmodulename-moduleexports) state that it should only be used on "extremely rare occasions" when "even a manual mock isn't suitable for your purposes" and adds that it is "*recommended to use [`jest.mock()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) instead.*"

In this case you aren't doing anything that would require `jest.setMock` so best practice is to activate your manual mock with `jest.mock`.

Comment: Any idea why `jest.mock('firebase-admin', () => ({firestore: () => {console.log('Im a mock')}}))` is not working? When in my test Jest is calling `admin.firebase()` is still using the import from the service and returning an error "The default Firebase app does not exist."  Here is the code: https://gist.github.com/Kosmonaft/cba1c0020383d33d4146668592ba42ed

Comment: `jest.mock` [doesn't work inside a test](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2582), move it to the top of your test file and it should work @Kosmonaft